# How to get App Url in Shopify Checkout extension

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

We are  developing a Checkout UI Extension that makes call to our own API to fetch the data. Right now we have hardcoded API's host URL, so we need to change it manually.Is there a way to add App url dynamically?

Comment: You can save the URL as a app metafield and get from it.